# Using Code First in Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

After Applying Code first paradigm in my Asp.net mvc3 app. The background DB had been created on the fly from code first When I run the app at the first time . But When I ran it again . I got a fat exception which said you can not create Database , because it exists . So I just don't know how to tell the EF do not create DB if the DB exists. Thanks.

Comment: Please use Google first next time... This is really basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may be useful to you

[EF Code First Existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343253/ef-code-first-existing-database)

Comment: Hi , friend , thank you for your reply, I had re-edited my question .thanks